# ASP.Net Core - best practice for accessing database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.Net Core (but not ASP.Net) and am wondering what's *the best way* to access an existing SQL Server database ?

I've followed some PluralSight tutorials, but they all seem to use the Code First approach.

Microsoft does have [some example code](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html) showing how to access an existing database though.

The reason I'm asking the question is that our company has hired an external company to write some code for us, and their solution was to do *all* of the database CRUD operations via Stored Procedures.

So, in SQL Server, they've basically created 3 Stored Procedures for each of the tables which the app uses, eg:

```
dbo.CustomerGet
dbo.CustomerDelete
dbo.CustomerUpdate
```

And their ASP.Net Core code just contains *loads* of small functions like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetCustomerOrders(int customerID)
{
    var itemsParams = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "@CustomerID", customerID}
    };
    var items = _dataAccess.GetData("dbo.CustomerOrdersGet", itemsParams,
        reader => new Order()
        {
            OrderID = reader.GetInt32(0),
            OrderName = reader.GetString(1),
            // ...etc...
        });
    return items;
}
```

The `GetData()` function just creates a new connection to the database, and calls that Stored Procedure:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string storedProcedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        return conn.Query<T>(storedProcedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

Their code doesn't mention `DbContext` anywhere.

Some of their SPs also do nothing more than a SELECT, but they take a PageNumber and PageSize parameter, to just get one page of data for a webpage, plus a "SortBy" parameter.

Again, in "my world", with manageable data sizes, I would always load all of the data in one go, and leave the client to look after showing one page of results, and handling the sorting.

I know StackOverflow isn't the ideal place for asking "what is your opinion ...?" type questions, but I'd appreciate some feedback.

And this **is** a genuine technical question, which **will** be useful to other developers, particularly given how new (and constantly changing) ASP.Net Core is.

I would've never written such code using "regular" ASP.Net, and am wondering what ASP.Net Core developers think of this method of coding.

(Btw, I am quite comfortable with stored procedures, I use them a lot in my in-house apps, but just on *data-intensive* operations, or when I don't want large sets of data being passed around between my SQL Server and ASP.Net code.  And I've never used a stored procedure just to, say, do a bog-standard SELECT on a table.)

Comment: This is have nothing to do with `ASP.NET Core`, I mean same kind of situation happened in other applications which uses other frameworks and programming languages.

Comment: Either way is viable. Both have their pros and cons. You're right, SO *isn't* the site for that.

Comment: @Fabio In fact, the .NET Framework app I maintain used exactly this approach, and it's a real dog's breakfast (which doesn't make the stored procedures approach _wrong_, it was just done very badly!)

Answer (score -1):

The ASP.NET code looks fine as they have created one generic method to call the stored procedure and fetch the dataset from SQL database.
And they are just calling that same generic method to fetch the information and then binding the result set with help of Reader. And its good option to use Stored Procedure even for the Select statements because if you will write direct Select Query in code then it might can lead to SQL Injection, so its good to use Stored Procedures and implement pagination at the SQL Server level because if you will fetch all data at one go then its obvious it will take more time in SP call and then you will save that data in ASP.NET object and then will apply ASP.NET paging which is not recommended. So its good to have:

a) Generic Method for SP Call in ASP.NET

b) Using Stored Procs to avoid SQL Injection

c) Using paginations in SQL Stored Procs to increase performance( this depends on the volume of data you have in tables)

Comment: Doesn't even begin to answer the question, as Entity Framework can handle all of that for you (often more intuitively).